# Recursion can't append list

Tags: python, recursion

Here I use a simplified code to demonstrate what I've encountered:

```
def recTry(inList):
    print(inList)
    if len(inList) < 10:
        recTry(inList.append(1))
```

I hope with recursion it'll grow like `[1]`, `[1, 1]`, `[1, 1, 1]` ...
But actually run that will yield this:

```
>>> recTry([1])
[1]
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in recTry
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in recTry
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

`inList` become `None` since the second recursion.
So How can I code to make the `inList` appended with each recursion?

Comment: your function is missing a `return` statement, and so it turns `None`

Comment: additionally `inList.append(1)` returns `None`. you'll need to first append 1, then pass the list to the recursive call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inList.append(1)` returns `None` so you pass `None`  while recursion

what you can do is:

```
def recTry(inList):
    print(inList)
    if len(inList) < 10:
        inList.append(1)
        recTry(inList)
    else:
        return inList
```

Answer (score 1):

you try to call function with result of inList.append(1) but it is None
try to:

```
if len(inList) < 10:
    inList.append(1)
    recTry(inList)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a convention in Python that methods that mutate sequences return None.  Thus the value your passing in first returns nothing which is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

On the 4th line of your function,

```
recTry(inList.append(1))
```

`inList.append(1)` returns None after appending 1 to the existing list. This `None` is what you are passing to recTry method. You can try this instead to make the `inList` appended with each recursion:

inList.append(1)
    recTry(inList)